# Is Nutiteq the tool that I need

Tags: c#, android, ios, nutiteq

I have a VS 2008 C# program that I would like to port to a mobile app.  It used Microsoft.sqlserver.types, geography, polygon, etc.  It does not need maps, connection to the internet, etc.  It calculated acreage, drew the polygon, never accessed or wrote to a DB file.  I am learning and playing with Xamarin (now that it is free).

I do realize that not all the C# code is applicable to Android and IOS, and some would have to be other code.  Can I do this same kind of coding\calculating, without accessing the internet, without  using maps, without accessing a DB (although that might be useful later on), etc...using Nutiteq (the free version), across Windows, Android, and IOS?

Answer (score 0):

Nutiteq SDK is specifically for display of maps. It has own geography objects and methods, not related to Microsoft.sqlserver. It is meant to replace e.g. Google/Apple maps, to have offline map view and routing features, and also some GIS: vector data editing, reading various GIS data formats like ShapeFile, GeoTIFF etc, and it works with native development on iOS and Android, and also Xamarin.

If you do not have any Map View, then probably Nutiteq SDK is not the best tool for your app.

Comment: I am working on VS 2015 Xamarin App using Map as a feature. Map feature is to mark the current coordinates on the map , just like pin on the map. What SDK, you recommend us to use ?? I am using google map, though not satisfied ..

Comment: please requesting  you to take a look on my post .. still active question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755929/how-to-get-current-location-coordinates-in-the-map-feature-in-xamarin-applicatio