# How to get current location coordinates in the Map feature in Xamarin Application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on location coordinates marking feature in the App.

I am using following dll's and google map.

```
Xamarin.Forms.Maps
Xam.Plugin.Geolocator
Xam.Plugin.ExternalMaps
```

In my iphone simulator, If the Location is NONE.It pulls default location some where in Rome, Italy

Following is the code written to pull the Map ..

```
public async Task<Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position> GetPosition()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position p;
            try
            {
                if (!locator.IsGeolocationAvailable)
                {
                    p = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position();
                }
                if (!locator.IsGeolocationEnabled)
                {
                    p = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position();
                }
                var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
                p = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(position.Latitude,position.Longitude);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                p = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position();
            }
            IsBusy = false;

            return p;
        }

        public async Task<object> GetCityName(double latitude, double longitude) { 
            HttpClient client;
            client = new HttpClient();
            client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(result);
                    var reValue = "" + json["results"][0]["formatted_address"];

                    var strArr = reValue.Split(',');
                    if (strArr.Length > 2)
                        return strArr[strArr.Length - 2] + ", " +strArr[strArr.Length - 1];
                    else
                        return "";
                }
                else {
                    Debug.WriteLine(@"Failed.");
                    return "Failed";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Image :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

elaborate your problem please, and change your conditions as follows:

```
if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable)
{
   if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationEnabled)
   {
      var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
      p = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(position.Latitude,position.Longitude);
   }
   else
   {
      throw new Exception("Geolocation is turned off");
      // Geolocation is turned off for the device.
   }
}
else
{ 
    throw new Exception("Geolocation is turned off");
    // Geolocation not available for device
}
```

Here now Handle the catches from `GetPosition()` Method to make sure you don't get the default location.